# Zend Currency Validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

How to validate currency values in Zend framework? Is there a default validator exists in zend framework or should I write my own one?

Answer (score 0):

The closest standard validator is [Zend_Validate_Float](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.float), that will validate the numbers. However you may find some of the functionality you need with the [Zend_Currency](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.currency.html) component. At least you should be able to use Zend_Currency to build a validator.

Answer (score 0):

If current locale is not a concern for you, you can use the Regex Validator

```
$costByCompletion = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('cost');

$costByCompletion->setLabel('Cost')
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->setValue("1.00")
         ->addValidator('Regex',false, array('pattern' =>'/^\$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]{2})?$/'));
```